# How can I make CCK field labels display differently on the node display page as opposed to the node add page?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a custom content type with form labels like this:

"Would you like to upload photos?"

That's appropriate for uploading data, but when displaying data to the world I'd just rather have:

"Photos:"

I see that there is a module for this, but it doesn't seem to be very well supported or used that much https://www.drupal.org/project/field_display_label. As well, this module doesn't seem to support 3rd party CCK field modules like Link.

Are there other modules out there? Also, I'm happy to approach it by creating module if someone would like to suggest how to get started or if you think a programmatic approach would be a better solution.

Comment: Field Display Label module is working and stable. What kind of problem did you have with it?

Comment: The module works great on all core fields, but for some, for example the link module (https://www.drupal.org/project/link) it doesn't seem to work.  Aside from that, it seems to work great.

Comment: Did you posted that issue on modules issue page?

Comment: I have not yet, but I will. If it's just a small bug and you believe it's stable enough to use, I'll move forward with it. That would probably answer the question as well, but I'll leave it open to see if someone wants to add a programmatic response for the sake of education.